# Limiting date range using Filter

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap

Without using the colon operator how do I filter the set `AllDates` to just 05Jan2005 to 10Jan2006?

```
WITH 
  SET [AllDates] AS 
    [Date].[Date].[Date].MEMBERS 
  MEMBER [Measures].[DTkey] AS 
    [Date].[Date].CurrentMember.Member_Key 
  MEMBER [Measures].[DTmemValue] AS 
    [Date].[Date].CurrentMember.MemberValue 
  MEMBER [Measures].[DTvalue] AS 
    [Date].[Date].CurrentMember.Value 
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[DTmemValue]} ON 0
 ,Filter
  (
    [AllDates]
   ,
    [Measures].[DTmemValue] > 0
  ) ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Comment: Comma-separated members?

Comment: @TabAlleman ok - fair comment: I've amended the question !

Comment: What is wrong with using colon?

Comment: @BIDude nothing wrong with it - range operator is lovely - just wondering if this is possible without using the colon

Comment: My quick Google search did not bring any alternatives

Comment: @BIDude seems bizarre as there are underlying values to date members so intuitively it seems that using filer should be possible?

Comment: Yes, it does. I took me a while to find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have Adv Wks but tested the below on mine and it worked well.

Is this what you're looking for?

```
WITH 
  SET [AllDates] AS 
    [Date].[date].[date].members
  MEMBER [Measures].[DTkey] AS 
    [Date].[date].CurrentMember.Member_Key 
  MEMBER [Measures].[DTmemValue] AS 
   [Date].[date].CurrentMember.MemberValue 
  MEMBER [Measures].[DTvalue] AS 
    [Date].[date].CurrentMember.Value 
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[DTmemValue]} ON 0
 ,Filter
  (
    [AllDates]
   ,
   CDate([Measures].[DTmemValue]) >= CDate("01/05/2005") 
   and CDate([Measures].[DTmemValue]) <= CDate("01/10/2006")
  ) ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Comment: hi sourav - I knew this would be possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH 
  SET [AllDates] AS 
    [Date].[Date].[Date].MEMBERS 
  MEMBER [Measures].[DTkey] AS 
    [Date].[Date].CurrentMember.Member_Key 
  MEMBER [Measures].[DTmemValue] AS 
    [Date].[Date].CurrentMember.MemberValue 
  MEMBER [Measures].[DTvalue] AS 
    [Date].[Date].CurrentMember.Value 
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[DTmemValue]} ON 0
 ,Filter
  (
    [AllDates]
   ,
    CDate([Measures].[DTmemValue]) > CDate("2006-01-01")
  ) ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

More details about MDX Filtering can be found: http://chrish.com.au/blog/filtering-in-mdx/